# Is there any difference between a non-singular, symmetric matrix and a positive definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

In optimization related context, you often see people impose the assumption that certain matrix is "symmetric and non-singular".

I wonder if this is the equivalent condition as the matrix being "positive definite".

It seems to be obvious, a positive definite matrix is symmetric (by standard assumption) and since all eigenvalues are real and positive, therefore non-singular.

At the same time, I know many characterizations of positive definite matrix, for instance, something about the determinants of the minors, eigenvalue characterization etc, but seldom have people mentioned that a matrix is positive definite matrix iff it is symmetric and non-singular. Maybe it is too obvious so people don't mention it.

So is there any meaningful distinction between these two sets of matrices?

Comment: It also seems to be obvious that a cat is an animal. Is there any meaningful distinction between the set of cats and the set of animals?

Comment: "but seldom have people mentioned that a matrix is positive definite matrix iff it is symmetric and non-singular. Maybe it is too obvious so people don't mention it."  I'm not sure you're going to cut it as a mathematician, but you could have a bright future as a stand-up comedian.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks! Not a mathematician by any means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ is symmetric and nonsingular but it is not positive definite because it has the eigenvalue $-1$.